# Event delegation in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm wondering if possible do create a event delegation from an object reference inside another object, this is the scenario.

I have 2 circles and 1 line between those two circles, every time any circle changes its own postition it have to update the line's position as well, by this time I have created a custom line that is going to have a reference to the two circles as a properties (origin, target)
but isn't binding the event in that way.

what I'm tryting to do is something like>

```
this.origin.on('dragstart dragmove',function(){
    console.log("origin mouse move");
    this.setPoints([origin.getX(),origin.getY(), target.getX(), target.getY()]);
    this.draw();
});
```

this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromullerrw/5Wkph/27/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buildArrow: function(origin,target){
    var arrowInstance = new Shape.Arrow({
       points: [origin.getX(),origin.getY(), target.getX(), target.getY()],
        stroke: '#629DD1',
        tension: 1
    });
    arrowInstance.origin=origin;
    origin.line = arrowInstance;

    arrowInstance.target=target;
    target.line = arrowInstance;
    return arrowInstance;
},
updatePosition : function() {
    this.points([this.origin.getX(),this.origin.getY(), this.target.getX(), this.target.getY()]);
},
```

Then:

```
this.on('dragstart dragmove',function(){
    var centerpoint = (this.cellSize/2)
     this.setX(((Math.round(this.getX() / centerpoint) * centerpoint)));
    this.setY(((Math.round(this.getY() / centerpoint) * centerpoint)));
    this.line.updatePosition();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/5Wkph/28/

Comment: that was very useful to clear up a little bit how to work with kinectJs, I just would like to know what's the purpose of using the line property on each object reference, thanks!